# Dividing triangulated polygon into smaller ones

Tags: graphics, geometry, triangulation

I have a polygon which has X number of vertices. The polygon is already triangulated into X-2 triangles. Let's assume that the polygon has 100000 vertices. How do I divide it into 2 polygons, so the number of vertices in one of them is 65535 or less(cannot be greater)?

Comment: *triangle stripping* algorithms might meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The dual graph (node for each triangle, arc for adjacent triangles) is a tree.  You could traverse this tree and keep track of how many nodes are in the subtrees determined by each node.  Because the nodes have degree at most three, you should be able to achieve your two-thirds goal.